# Larger Private Data reserved in Win10 compare with Win7

Tags: memory-management, windows-10, windows-7-x64, reserved, vmmap

I run the same application on Windows 10 and Windows 7 (both 64-bit) and used Process Explorer to monitor the Virtual Size. I noticed that the Virtual Size of the application running on Windows 10 is much larger than running on Windows 7.

By using VMMap, in Private Data:

Windows 10 - 1 address with 4.2GB is reserved and not committed.

Windows 7  - 2 address with 15MB are reserved and not committed.

So my questions are:

1. Why there is a large memory has been reserved? Is it just a different memory management done by Win10 and Win7?
2. Or, there is something to do with the application that I ran? (The application has no problem to run on Win10 & Win7)
3. Is there any suitable indicator to track memory leak? (Eg: 'Committed' value in VMMap) It seems like so much discussion/argument on this :P

Comment: windows has something called CFG (Control Flow Guard) since 8.1 and this requires a larger amount of reserved bytes

Comment: Thanks for the info! @magicandre1981 I also found  that this private data with the same size (4.2GB) appeared in other processes such as Chrome.exe and explorer.exe. Is it means that some processes only required the exist of CFG?